# How to use JQuery with Angular without directives?

Tags: angularjs

In an AngularJS app, is there any way that I can use JQuery without directives?
Directives seem hard to use, and I don't want to go back to the JSF way that every DOM related things should be in directives. Can I use JQuery in the view directly? and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trust me, just get in the habit of making quick, little directives to handle your jQuery needs. By it's nature, Angular handles lots of the DOM manipulation that you WOULD use jQuery for for you. And when you do need to access jQuery objects, just do something like this:

```
myApp.directive("sortable", function() {
    return function(scope, element) {
        element.sortable(<options>);
    }
}
```

I always end up with lots of these in projects, and they can be some of the most useful, simple, powerful directives you make. If you want to, directives also let you pass custom attributes, which can be really handy, like:

```
<div resizable min-width="200" max-width="600" handle="e, w">
```

You just have to go through the process of banging out 10 or 15 of these "simple" directives, and it will become natural.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has a lite version of JQuery and it is not like you have to go back `ab initio` to write directives - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

It is recommended not to do direct DOM manipulations and instead go with directives in AngularJS. There is the learning curve, but take the time to cross it.

Answer (score 0):

In angular UI they have given provision for that you can check (jQuery Passthrough - Call the jQuery function or plugin specified on the element) @ http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

In that they have showed how to call the bootstrap tooltip with almost no work